# Zoom automatically in the feature after clicking on it in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom

Is it possible that after clicking a feature in QGIS to zoom automatically there?

Comment: Your title suggest that you are selecting the feature in order to know what to zoom to but your question body makes no mention of that detail.

Comment: It is not possible to zoom to a feature just by clicking on it, you first must select the feature you would like to zoom to, then right-click and zoom to the selected feature. Otherwise, use the pan tool to zoom in and out.

Comment: @PolyGeo u r right. I edit the title of my question. Thank you.

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus after selecting feature I don't want to Right click, but to automatically zoom in the selected feature.

Answer (score 7):

I think a layer Action might work well for your use case.

Open the layer properties dialog, click the Actions tab then click the green plus sign to add a new action:

[image]

Configure the action as below- Select Python type action, give it a name, select Canvas scope and paste the following Python code into the Action text editor:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
fid = [%$id%]
layer_obj = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFeatureIds(layer_obj, [fid])
```

Then click ok to accept both dialogs.

[image]

Now, when you click on your layer in the Table of Contents panel, the actions button will be enabled in the Attributes toolbar.

[image]

Click the drop down arrow next to the actions button and select your action name to activate it. A new map canvas map tool will be set with a cross cursor. Clicking on any feature in your layer will result in zooming to that feature (if there are overlapping features you will get a pop-up which allows you to choose one or all features). To de-activate the action, just select a different map tool.

Answer (score 4):

With playing a little bit with Python QGIS API, I wrote the code below that do what you want (Ubuntu 18.04, QGIS 3.8).

Just select the layer in the layer tree under QGIS and execute the code in the Python console :

```py
def zoom_new_selected_feature(
    selected: list,
    deselected: list,
    clearAndSelect: bool
):
    # if the length of the selected features ids
    # is > 0, then:
    if len(selected) > 0:
        # retrieve the bounding box of selected features
        bbox = vl.boundingBoxOfSelected()
        # set the new mapCanvas extent to the new bounding box
        iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(bbox)

# define vl as the QgsVectorLayer selected in the interface
# (layer underlined in the layer tree)
vl = iface.activeLayer()

# try to disconnect the signal in case of it was already
# connected to avoid a double connection
try:
    vl.selectionChanged.disconnect(zoom_new_selected_feature)
except TypeError:
    pass

"""
connect the function `zoom_new_selected_feature`
to the `selectionChanged` signal (QgsVectorLayer signal).
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.selectionChanged
"""
vl.selectionChanged.connect(zoom_new_selected_feature)
```

Comment: I tried it and nothing happens. can you explain me step by step please?

Comment: @EsHo: I added comments in my code, hope that help.